# Find the differential equation of all circles of radius a

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles

Can someone please post a detailed step-by-step procedure. Given the circle with a radius a, what is the differential equation of the circle.

Comment: quoting you, "what is the differential equation of the circle"?

Comment: Please reopen, it seems pretty clear what is asked, even Wolfram Alpha can verify the usual differential equations for circles and the like: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d+x%28t%29%2Fdt+%3D+y%28t%29+and+d+y%28t%29%2Fdt+%3D+-x%28t%29 which is found in the answer of @lhf .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the implicit equation of the circle $(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2=a^2$, you get $$x'(x-u)+y'(y-v)=0$$ by implicit differentiation. Add the initial condition $$x(0)=u+a, \quad y(0)=v$$

You can write the differential equations as
$$
x'=-y+v, \quad y' = x-u
$$
which is especially nice for circles centered at the origin.

Comment: Thanks Norbert and lhf. Appreciate your answers. I am however surprised to see clean mathematical notations here. Do you use any software as such to paste these equations here? (Pardon me, I am using math.stackexchange for the first time.

Comment: @Nikhil, this site understands TeX. View the source of the web pages to see how it's done. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help. Welcome to MSE.

Comment: Thanks :-) BTW, I was also wondering if there is any kind of math application, which would give me sort of help to find the steps as in for example: Evaluate the integral x^2 (sqrt(a pow3 + x pow3)) dx.

Answer (score 9):

Circle equation
$$
(x-C_1)^2+(y-C_2)^2=a^2\quad (0)
$$
Differentiate twice by $x$
$$
(x-C_1)+y'(y-C_2)=0\quad (1)
$$
$$
1+(y-C_2)y''+(y')^2=0\quad (2)
$$
From $(2)$ we obtain
$$
C_2=y+\frac{(y')^2+1}{y''}
$$
Then substitute in $(1)$ and $(0)$
$$
(x-C_1)-y'\frac{(y')^2+1}{y''}=0\quad(3)
$$
$$
(x-C_1)^2+\left(\frac{(y')^2+1}{y''}\right)^2=a^2\quad(4)
$$
From $(3)$ we obtain
$$
x-C_1=y'\frac{(y')^2+1}{y''}
$$
Then substitute in $(4)$
$$
\left(y'\frac{(y')^2+1}{y''}\right)^2+\left(\frac{(y')^2+1}{y''}\right)^2=a^2
$$
After some simplifications we get
$$
((y')^2+1)^3=(ay'')^2
$$

Comment: Why is there an arbitrary constant "a" in the final answer ? Shouldn't it be eliminated?

Comment: @RohitJoshi, no. Please read the original question.

Comment: @Norbet If you mean radius is not arbitrary as it is fixed as 'a', also the center is fixed as (h,k). Then why are h and k eliminated ?

Comment: @RohitJoshi, someone added a confusing correction to the question headline. Now fixed. The original question said nothing about the center of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

We can express standard result/formula for curvature rectangular coordinates

$$  \frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}  =\frac{1}{a} $$

as the required differential equation.

EDIT 1:

In polar co-ordinates the ODE for curvature is

$$ \dfrac { r^2 +  2 r ^{'2 }- r r ^{"} }{ (r^2 +r'^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{a} \tag{1}$$

The above can be derived from  *intrinsic/natural* differential equation of a circle is

$$ \frac{d \phi }{ds} = \frac{d (\theta + \psi ) }{ds}=\frac{1}{a}\tag{2}$$

$$ =\dfrac{ \sin \psi}{r} + \frac{d}{ds} ( \tan ^{-1} \frac{r}{r'} )  \tag{3}  $$

where $\phi$ is angle to x-axis, $ \psi$ is between arc and radius vector, $$ \tan \psi = \dfrac {r}{r^{'}}  \tag{4} $$

Introducing above into (3) and differentiating, LHS is

$$  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ r^2 +r'^2  }} + \frac{r'^2 - r r ^{''}}{ r^2 +r'^2  } \frac{1}{\sqrt{ r^2 +r'^2  }} \tag{5=1}  $$