# Obtain the Differential Equation of all circles of radius $r$ .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles, differential

Equation of circles of radius $r$ :-

$$
{( x-a)}^2 +{(y - b)^2} = r^2
$$

Then I treated $a,b,r$ as arbitrary constants .

And differentiated the equation *thrice* .

which gave the wrong result

As in the solution in the book equation was differentiated *twice* .

> So why do we not treat $r$ as *arbitrary constant and differentiate it twice* ?

***My question is very different from "[Find the differential equation of all circles of radius a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88070/find-the-differential-equation-of-all-circles-of-radius-a)" as this question is aking what to do whereas i am asking why do not we take radius as arbitrary.***

Comment: @LutzL: I agree with the OP that this is not a duplicate. Voting to reopen.

Comment: If we are talking about "circles of radius $r$" then only the parameters $a$ and $b$ in your setup are variable. The resulting ODE is of second order and has to reflect that the curvature of the solution curves is $={1\over r}$.

Answer (score 2):

The question should be interpreted as “find the differential equation for all circles of a *fixed* (given) radius $r$”. If you treat $r$ as arbitrary, you get the differential equations for *all* circles, no matter what radius.

Comment: NO, the question does not contain _'given radius'_ , it simply states only radius .

Comment: @MIKEY: Exactly! That's why you have to do a bit of **interpretation** to understand what the question is **intended** to mean. And it's safe to say, from experience with how math questions are usually formulated, that when a number just pops up in the way that $r$ does here, it's intended to be a parameter in the problem, which has an arbitrary but fixed value (so that the answer will most likely depend on that parameter). Otherwise whoever posed the question wouldn't have bothered mentioning it.

Comment: @HandLundmark Is there any other question in which we have to ourselves take some constant as fixed ?

Comment: There are so many examples, I don't know where to start... “Find the distance from the origin to the line $3x+y=d$”, perhaps?